# Red & white dotted line on outside of view

Tags: mesh

Idk what I pressed but I can't get this red & white dotted line to disappear. It's preventing me from using my shift/ctrl movements with mouse scroller while having circular/rectangular selection active. Anywho know how to deactivate it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The border looks like a [Render Border](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html) (activated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> in the 3D view in Object Mode). It can be deactivated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

I don't think it's connected with navigation being disabled while in brush (circle) select mode. The scroll-wheel is taken over to determine the size of the brush, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> is occupied to switch from select to deselect.

Comment: Your a lifesaver buddy! Tried it and it worked. Thanks alot for responding to this thread! : D

Comment: If that answer solved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) @The.Boyfriend